# How many triangles from a set of pairs?

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of of pairs that looks like this `[{a,b},{c,b},{d,f},{d,b},{a,d},{c,e},{a,f},...]`.

I need to find out which and how many of those pairs can be connected into a triangle. The order doesn't matter.

One possible solution would for example be `[{d,f},{a,d},{a,f}]`, because those are the 3 sides to the triangle `△FDA`.

I've mocked up this little picture to better illustrate the problem:

[image]

I'm actually sitting over this problem for days now, but any idea I came up with, I had to discard.

There's no guarantee that these triangles can be built from the pairs in any way. The set is allowed to have a non-infinite, chaotic number of pairs.

Comment: This question seems to essentially be: *how do I compute the number of triangles in a graph?*

Comment: Notice that it suffices to choose two pairs to define a triangle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a straightforward solution: simply go over every possible way to choose three edges and check if they form a triangle.

A simple potential improvement over this is to instead get the list of all<sup>1</sup> vertices and go over every possible way to choose three vertices and check if they form a triangle.

This variation definitely requires that you store edges in a data structure that allows efficient membership tests (e.g. a hash table; in python you could use an instance of `set`).

<sub>1: Actually, I mean just the vertices incident with at least one edge</sub>

---

If it turns out that the straightforward approach doesn't meet your actual needs, here is an alternative.

First, for every vertex $A$, construct the list $\mathrm{Adjacent}(A)$ whose elements are all vertices adjacent to $A$.

(it's likely you will want to build all the lists in one loop where you go over each edge and update the two vertex lists)

Next, for every vertex $A$, you do the following. You search through all pairs of elements $B,C \in \mathrm{Adjacent}(A)$, and check if the edge $BC$ is in your set of edges.

(again you want the edges in a structure that allows efficient membership testing)

This algorithm finds each triangle three times. You can avoid redundant work by ordering the vertices. Then, for example, for each $A$, you might search only over the pairs $B,C \in \mathrm{Adjacent}(A)$ for which both vertices are larger than $A$.

(another possibility that might be even better is to search over $B$ less than $A$ and $C$ greater than $A$)

---

Another way to use these lists is the following algorithm:

- Iterate over every edge $AB$

  - Compute the intersection $\mathrm{Adjacent}(A) \cap \mathrm{Adjacent}(B)$

Every vertex $C$ in the intersection will yield a triangle $ABC$.

There are a number of ways to compute intersections of lists. One generic method is if you have a way to sort vertices. Then make sure every list is sorted, and you can find the intersection by iterating through both lists. (in just one pass through)

This also benefits from the trick of the previous section to avoid doing redundant work.

Comment: This solution is nice because I immediately get the info of which vertices make up a triangle. The amount of triangles can then simply be counted afterwards. Unfortunately the second part of this solution is very time-consuming. Assuming that on average every vertex has 100 edges, searching through all pairs would take 4950 loops to run for each vertex. At 1000 vertices, a loop would run almost 5 million times.

Comment: @Dominik: That's a big graph; only 5 million iterations sounds like a very good time. The more straightforward solution of checking every triple of edges would take 125 trillion iterations. Even checking every triple of vertices instead (which is the better straightforward solution; I'll update my answer) would still require a billion iterations.

Comment: @Dominik: Note, incidentally, that such a graph averages over 150 thousand triangles. (assuming each edge is present with independent probability 1/10, you'll average one triangle in every thousand ways to pick three vertices)

Comment: And in the worst case (10 cliques of 100 vertices), there are actually roughly 1.7 million triangles!

Comment: Wow that last method you just added might be incredible for my use case. Since I already have the edges to begin with, I only need to calculate the adjacent lists, then with 100 edges I only have to run the intersection algorythm 100 times. Now I just need to figure out how to do intersections efficiently. If that doesn't add much, this solution might be a time-complexity monster!

Comment: I've implemented the last solution, the one with the intersections. You mention that it's possible to avoid redundant work and only get unique triangles. This is exactly where I'm struggling. I only figured out how to get 3 or 6 permutations. It would be really great, if you could elaborate on that in your answer. I just can't see, how I can cross anything off a sorted list, with the intersection and edge approach.

Comment: @Dominik: I think the simplest is to only search for $A < C < B$, so only one of the three edges let you find the triangle. And such $C$ lie in the intersection $\mathrm{AdjacentToAndGreaterThan}(A) \cap \mathrm{AdjacentToAndLessThan}(B)$.

Answer (score 2):

If you represent your graph as an [adjacency matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) $A$, where $A_{ij}$ represents the number of edges that go from node $i$ to node $j$, then let $P=A^n$, $P_{ij}$ represents the number of paths of length $n$ from $i$ to $j$. From $P$, we can see that the main diagonal has paths of length three that start and end at the same vertex, which is exactly what you're looking for. So we add up all the elements of the main diagonal (also known as the *trace* of a graph). However, for any triangle, this sum will count it six times over because we would count $ADF$ as $ADF,\ AFD,\ DAF,\ DFA,\ FAD,\text{ and } FDA$. This is easy enough to fix, we just divide the sum by six.

Formally, the exact equation is $\text{trace}(A^3)/6$, where $A$ is the adjacency matrix.

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/number-of-triangles-in-a-undirected-graph/) is a more detailed explanation.

Comment: This is a really great solution for counting the triangles. Unfortunately it doesn't have any information about which vertices make up the triangle. I'm trying to come up with a way to apply this method to finding the vertices. My idea is that every vertex that has 2 distinct walks and 1 distinct walk is a vertex that makes up a triangle. So one needs to compare A and A^2 (with the "self-walks" deleted from the trace of A^2). What do you think about this?

Comment: You can examine the diagonal of $A^3$ for some more information because $A^3_{ii}\over2$ tells you how many triangles contain vertex $i$, which will get you a good starting point for whatever algorithm you use because you'll know when to stop using the algorithm. From there, you can use a backtracking algorithm, starting with the vertex in the fewest number of triangles. Whenever you find a triangle, e.g. $abd$, you decrease the count you have for $a$, $b$, and $d$.