# How to determine the number of triads from a set of pairs?

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations

I have a set of paired numbers as follows:

```
 { 
   {{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5}},  
   {{2,3},{2,4},{2,5}},   
   {{3,4},{3,5}},  
   {4,5}  
 }
```

- (a) How can I calculate the number of unique triads, such that only 3 digits appear in each triad? In the example above, one triad would be: `{{1,2},{1,3},{2,3}}`. So in the set above, we would have 10 such sets.
- (b) What is the general formula, given $n$ number of items (or numbers, if you like) for the number of *triads*?
- (c) What is the correct mathematical language to describe this problem?

The number of unique *pairs* is given by the shifted [triangular series](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/triangular-numbers.html): $k = n(n-1)/2$ = 10.
It can also be obtained through the ${n \choose m} = {5 \choose 2} = 10$

---

Possibly related questions:

- [How many triangles from a set of pairs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2592565/how-many-triangles-from-a-set-of-pairs)

---

**Clarification:**

The answer for the 10 triads I am looking to calculate are:

```
{ 
  {12,13,23}, {12,14,24}, {12,15,25}, {13,14,34}, {13,15,35}, {14,15,45},  
  {23,24,34}, {23,25,35}, 
  {34,35,45}
}
```

Comment: Why do you believe there are six, not ten, triangles in your example?

Comment: Because: (a) I counted them: `{{12,13,23}, {12,14,24}, {12,15,25}, {13,14,34}, {13,15,35},{14,15,45}}` where I have used simplified notation. (b) I am probably not using the correct language to describe the situation.

Comment: Your list lacks $\{2,3,4\}$, $\{2,3,5\}$, $\{2,4,5\}$, and $\{3,4,5\}$, for each of which all three pairs are present in your lists of pairs.

Comment: @EricTowers Oops, you're absolutely right! I'll edit my post.

Comment: Your set has all the possible pairs of numbers from 1 to 5. It can be visualized as the complete graph of 5 vertices. The number of triads is the number of possibilities of triangles, given 5 vertices, that is, 5 choose 3.

Comment: @AndréPorto If you post your answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: For your specific case where $n=5$, it can be noted that there is an easy way to go from a pair to a triad by looking at a pair and using the triad which consists of all those elements which you *didn't* previously use... so $\{1,2\}\mapsto \{3,4,5\}$ and $\{2,4\}\mapsto\{1,3,5\}$ etc...  showing that the number of pairs is exactly equal to the number of triads.  This clearly doesn't work for when $n$ is not equal to $5$, the number of pairs and triads being different, but it does lead to a proof of the result that $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to André Porto's comment, I learned something about [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) and [complete graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph). The *complete graph* on $n$ vertices is denoted by $K_n$. In our case $n=5$ so that the $K_5$ graph look like this:

[image]

The number of triads are equivalent to the number of connected edges, given by:

$r = {n \choose k} = {5 \choose 3} = 10$

Coincidentally, this is also equivalent to ${5 \choose 2}$, as was the case for the number of *pairs*. Also, notice how each vertex is connected to the other four.